# How often should soft fruit plants be replaced?

Tags: strawberries, raspberries, soft-fruit, lifespan

We inherited blackcurrants, gooseberries, raspberries and strawberries when we moved into our current property ten years ago.

The blackcurrants and gooseberries still seem to be giving a healthy yield and it looks like they'll go on for nearly for ever. The strawberries and raspberries started to fade about 5 years ago and we have removed them.

What's the recommended lifespan for strawberries and raspberries?

Comment: I've known people who replace strawberries every other year.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Raspberries can grow productively longer, to around 10 years, as long as you rejuvenate/prune the fruiting canes properly. Strawberries, like JonH said, get around 3 productive years of fruit-bearing before they succumb to disease and age, giving it a lifespan of 4 years or so.

Comment: What are the main causes of disease in these plants? Aphids (which can transmit diseases to plants), or something else? I wonder how long they would live in a sterile, pest-free greenhouse.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't a set timeframe, but for strawberries and raspberries, you can usually get a good 3 seasons out of these fruits before it is time to replace.  So I usually stick with 3-4 years, and you will definately notice it as the yield of fruit decreases as time goes on.